# Searching for implementations of multilabel feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, multilabel-classification

Does anyone know of any packages that implement multilabel feature selection algorithms? There are many papers introducing algorithms, but few if any seem to be implemented publicly. I have been able to adapt some standard feature selection algorithms for multilabel, but I'd really like to employ some specifically designed for the task

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Multilabel classification is essentially the same as training N independent binary classifiers, with N the number of possible labels. So in this case I think that I would do feature selection for each independent binary classifier, in order to find the optimal set of features for every label.

Comment: Thanks @Erwan! Thats what I'm currently doing. I was hoping to use some of the algorithms specifically designed for multilabel classification, because the main difference between multilabel and binary classification is the potential for dependence between labels. Unfortunately, feature selection on N binary classifiers would miss that. It seems that most of the multilabel specific algorithms haven't been implemented publicly though

Comment: Ok I see. Genetic feature selection could be an option, but it requires training/testing many times so it depends how heavy the training process is.